# TrueType Font "droid" broken for PdfLaTex in MikTeX?

Tags: fonts, packages, miktex, truetype

Using latest MikTeX (clean install on Windows 10 x64) with latest `droid`-package (version 3.2) I am not able do get droid fonts to be embedded as TrueType font in PDF – now all fonts are bitmaps. There was a previous version of the `droid`-package where the issue did not occur. From one version to another version `\usepackage{droid}` did not work any more ("File `droidmono.sty` not found" in `droid.sty`). According to the doc we have to `\usepackage{droidsans}` now.

Example (see result image below):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  % oder ...

  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  % oder auch nicht
}


\usepackage[german]{babel}
% oder was auch immer


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{droid}
%\usepackage{helvet}



%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}


\title[Kurzversion des Titels] % (optional, nur bei langen Titeln nötig)
{Titel}

\subtitle
{Untertitel} % (optional)

\author[Autor, Anders] % (optional, nur bei vielen Autoren)
{F.~Autor\inst{1} \and S.~Anders\inst{2}}
% - Der \inst{?} Befehl sollte nur verwendet werden, wenn die Autoren
%   unterschiedlichen Instituten angehören.

\institute[Universitäten Hier und Dort] % (optional, aber oft nötig)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Institut für Informatik\\
  Universität Hier
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Institut für theoretische Philosophie\\
  Universität Dort}
% - Der \inst{?} Befehl sollte nur verwendet werden, wenn die Autoren
%   unterschiedlichen Instituten angehören.
% - Keep it simple, niemand interessiert sich für die genau Adresse.

\date[Kurzversion des Anlass] % (optional)
{Datum / Anlass}


\subject{Informatik}
% Dies wird lediglich in den PDF Informationskatalog einfügt. Kann gut
% weggelassen werden.


% Falls eine Logodatei namens "university-logo-filename.xxx" vorhanden
% ist, wobei xxx ein von latex bzw. pdflatex lesbares Graphikformat
% ist, so kann man wie folgt ein Logo einfügen:

% \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
% \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}



% Folgendes sollte gelöscht werden, wenn man nicht am Anfang jedes
% Unterabschnitts die Gliederung nochmal sehen möchte.
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Gliederung}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}


% Falls Aufzählungen immer schrittweise gezeigt werden sollen, kann
% folgendes Kommando benutzt werden:

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Gliederung}
  \tableofcontents
  % Die Option [pausesections] könnte nützlich sein.
\end{frame}



% Da dies ein Vorlage für beliebige Vorträge ist, lassen sich kaum
% allgemeine Regeln zur Strukturierung angeben. Da die Vorlage für
% einen Vortrag zwischen 15 und 45 Minuten gedacht ist, fährt man aber
% mit folgenden Regeln oft gut.  

% - Es sollte genau zwei oder drei Abschnitte geben (neben der
%   Zusammenfassung). 
% - *Höchstens* drei Unterabschnitte pro Abschnitt.
% - Pro Rahmen sollte man zwischen 30s und 2min reden. Es sollte also
%   15 bis 30 Rahmen geben.



\section{Einleitung}

\subsection[Kurzversion des ersten Unterabschnittstitels]
{Erster Unterabschnittstitel}

\begin{frame}{Überschriften müssen informativ sein.\\
    Korrekte Groß-/Kleinschreibung beachten.}{Untertitel sind optional.}
  % - Eine Überschrift fasst einen Rahmen verständlich zusammen. Man
  %   muss sie verstehen können, selbst wenn man nicht den Rest des
  %   Rahmens versteht.

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Viel \texttt{itemize} benutzen.
  \item
    Sehr kurze Sätze oder Satzglieder verwenden.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Überschriften müssen informativ sein.}

  Man kann Overlays erzeugen\dots
  \begin{itemize}
  \item mit dem \texttt{pause}-Befehl:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Erster Punkt.
      \pause
    \item    
      Zweiter Punkt.
    \end{itemize}
  \item
    mittels Overlay-Spezifikationen:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<3->
      Erster Punkt.
    \item<4->
      Zweiter Punkt.
    \end{itemize}
  \item
    mit dem allgemeinen \texttt{uncover}-Befehl:
    \begin{itemize}
      \uncover<5->{\item
        Erster Punkt.}
      \uncover<6->{\item
        Zweiter Punkt.}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Zweiter Unterabschnittstitel}

\begin{frame}{Überschriften müssen informativ sein.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Überschriften müssen informativ sein.}
\end{frame}

\section*{Zusammenfassung}

\begin{frame}{Zusammenfassung}

  % Die Zusammenfassung sollte sehr kurz sein.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Die \alert{erste Hauptbotschaft} des Vortrags in ein bis zwei Zeilen.
  \item
    Die \alert{zweite Hauptbotschaft} des Vortrags in ein bis zwei Zeilen.
  \item
    Eventuell noch eine \alert{dritte Botschaft}, aber nicht noch mehr.
  \end{itemize}

  % Der folgende Ausblick ist optional.
  \vskip0pt plus.5fill
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Ausblick
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Etwas, was wir noch nicht lösen konnten.
    \item
      Nochwas, das wir noch nicht lösen konnten.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered PDF]

[image: Fonts in PDF]

Comment: the package has an error, it should do `\RequirePackage[defaultmono]{droidsansmono}` (or rename the sty). Report this to the maintainer of the package. And miktex has an error, it didn't activate the `droidsansmono.map` and `droidserif.map`. Report this in the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you! I replaced to `\RequirePackage[defaultmono]{droidsansmono}`, but then `Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: …\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.` and `Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: …\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log` occurred.

Comment: yes, I said miktex didn't activate the map-file. So report the error, and also report it to the author of the package.

Comment: 2019-11-01 20:19:28,782+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance -q -t DroidSansMono-T1--base
2019-11-01 20:19:29,207+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font DroidSansMono-T1--base could not be created.

Comment: 2019-11-01 20:19:28,719+0100 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose DroidSansMono-T1--base
2019-11-01 20:19:28,735+0100 FATAL miktex-makemf - The DroidSansMono-T1--base source file could not be found.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you, I will report it …

Comment: @Ronny did you get any feedback from the author? the error in `droid.sty` is still present to date in CTAN as far as I can see, and the package is still broken for me (editing `droid.sty` as suggested by Ulrike Fischer does the trick.

Comment: @odony, as far as know, the MikTeX author fixed the issue for MikTeX. I don’t know any more if I had contacted the author of the package – sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed in latest MikTeX release.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using

```
\usepackage{droidmono}
```

before, replacing it by

```
\usepackage{droidsansmono}
```

seems to work.